Landscape: Add Third Party Repository
All of our workstations are managed by our landscape - and I want to add and attach the CRAN Repositories ( https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ ) to our workstations.
How do I add a mirror? I tried different values for URL and mirror suite - but nothing really works.
Does someone have working values?

Alternatively: Would a better option be to just add the apt line? How do I provide the public key to the client with this option?

Write a script that does the steps - key obtaining, installation, setup, then creation of the file that holds the repository entry.  Deploy that to relevant hosts/groups/tags with the Scripts option in Landscape.

Ah, ok. Then using the mirror-function in landscape's repositoy system would be better ;-)
Do you have an idea what values may be best for this?

I'll have to look @ Landscape and get back to you I haven't done much lately in Landscape.  I'm also in a training all day

No problem. The funny thing is, even after 20 years of debian administration, I have absolutely now idea how e.g. deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu noble-cran40/ can be translated to this syntax ;-)

Are the workstations 22.04 and older or newer?  Asking because the script will be different for each.

I just found out that I added the mirror right - the error is now a  b"/usr/bin/unlzma: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt '/usr/bin/unlzma' < ./lists/update-noble_%2F_Packages.lzma > ./lists/update-noble_%2F_Packages exited with errorcode 1! Error reading from ./lists/update-noble_%2F_Packages.lzma: Trailing garbage after compressed data! There have been errors!"

A script to add the repository is nice but would not really help, scripting is switched off on the workstations ;-)
Damn, I will just debug deeper into this landscape, maybe the problem is on a proxy server or the cran repository itself

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In this case, the CRAN40-Repository really seems to have corrupted lzma files (maybe due to xz vs lzma).
If you are interested on how "flat-repositories" are added in general, have a look for this NVIDIA-Example:
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-mirror-and-manage-repositories-with-the-api/23086/6
You can recognize flat-repositories if they only have a "/" as distribution or are ending with a /
